# How to Extrude svg shape using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a set of svg shapes like circle, triangle and polygon, I try to extrude those shapes using javascript.

I have tried with JS Animation and 3.Js but I am not able to figure out.

The result should be on Click of particular shape,it should Extrude

Comment: Extrude, as in make 3D with WebGL?

Comment: Yes with 3D @Brad